# Задача php для начинающих

Tags: php

Господа подсобите с решением пожалуйста
Дан массив $data, содержащий базу данных авторов и книг этой библиотеки.

Выведите следующую информацию на сайте:

1. Выведи строку: === Авторы ===
2. Выведите всех авторов на сайте. Каждый автор должен быть на отдельной строке, при этом формат вывода должен быть следующий:

Имя автора – его email – его год рождения.

3. Выведи строку: === Книги ===
4. Выведите все книги на сайте. Каждая книга должна быть на отдельной строке, при этом формат вывода должен быть следующий:

Название книги – имя автора - год выпуска книги.

Внимание!
Для решении задачи запрещено использовать функции, анонимные функции, преобразование типов, классы, базу данных, другие переменные, кроме $data.

вводные данные

```
$data = [
    'authors' => [
        301 => [
            'id' => 301,
            'name' => 'Александр Сергеевич Пушкин',
            'email' => 'alexander_pushkin@example.com',
            'birthYear' => 1799,
        ],
        10 => [
            'id' => 10,
            'name' => 'Николай Васильевич Гоголь',
            'email' => 'nikolay_gogol@example.com',
            'birthYear' => 1809,
        ],
        17 => [
            'id' => 17,
            'name' => 'Михаил Юрьевич Лермонтов',
            'email' => 'mikhail_lermontov@example.com',
            'birthYear' => 1814,
        ],
    ],
    'books' => [
        [
            'title' => 'Евгений Онегин',
            'publishedAt' => '1823—1832',
            'author' => 301,
        ],
        [
            'title' => 'Полтава',
            'publishedAt' => '1828—1829',
            'author' => 301,
        ],
        [
            'title' => 'Мёртвые души',
            'publishedAt' => '1842',
            'author' => 10,
        ],
        [
            'title' => 'Сказка о рыбаке и рыбке',
            'publishedAt' => '1833',
            'author' => 301,

        ],
    ],
];
```

Comment: а что Вас останавливает от решения этой задачи?

Comment: хотя бы названия элементов массива дали

Comment: а что такое "название элементов массива"? может содержимое?

Comment: 1 останавливает отсутствие знаний.
2 поправил
3 вот как поставлена задача - так я ее изложил

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: меня интересует логика, так сказать первый шаг с чего начать.

Comment: @Genjo [Вот, пожалуйста](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/langref.php).

Comment: @KoVadim вы прочитали условие? Там нельзя использовать другие переменные, нельзя изменять изначальную чтобы хранить что-то в ней, плюс хранить в функциях, классах, БД, из-за того что не использовать функции также и не воспользоваться файлами... Задание вообще выглядит нерешаемым, потому что остаются конструкции php т.е. ключевые слова, а для хранения в них использовать ничего не получится. $_Session похоже также будет другая переменная.

Comment: @KirS - Видите ли, вот внизу человек предложил решение и автор вопроса его принял. Значит, не все так однозначно.

Comment: @KoVadim А как вы думаете я этот вопрос нашёл?)) У меня такая же задача! Не буду же я новый создавать

Comment: Тогда расскажите поподробнее, где эту задачу взяли и почему такие ограничения. И знает ли вопрошающий Вас, как ее решать

Comment: @KoVadim Задача популярная, взята скорее всего из какого-то одного источика - её юзают для проверки кандидатов. Знают или нет не отвечу - там такое условие. Кстати тут не хватает условия про изменение массивов. Но я когда решал его тоже опустил и добавлял данные в отдельный раздел массива $data

Comment: подсказываю, как решаются такие задачи. На собеседовании встаете, идете к HR, говорите, что их программист не компетентен и выходите с здания (завершаете миттинг). Все. Если задают такие задания - значит дальше будет жесть ещё больше. Но Вы так и не сообщили, где же задали такое задание

Comment: @KoVadim Ну это электронная проверка, как тест, там митинга нет. Выйти только в окно.

Comment: ну тогда просто закрываете окно браузера и отписываетесь, что извините, это не мне

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo '<b> === Авторы ===</b><br>';
array_map(function($e){
    echo sprintf('%s – %s – %s',$e['name'], $e['email'], $e['birthYear']) . '<br>';
}, $data['authors']);

echo '<b> === Книги ===</b><br>';
array_map(function($e){
    echo sprintf('%s – %s – %s',$e['title'], $e['publishedAt'], $e['author']) . '<br>';
}, $data['books']);
```

Что еще за вас сделать? :)

Comment: Вы использовали функции array_map, sprintf, анонимную функцию и другую переменную $e. Вы не просто не соблюли заданное условие но и намеренно его нарушили. Вопрос хороший.