# Вывод массива php в определенном формате

Tags: php, массивы, вывод

есть массив данных условной библиотеки:

```
    $data = [
    'authors' => [
        301 => [
            'id' => 301,
            'name' => 'Александр Сергеевич Пушкин',
            'email' => 'alexander_pushkin@example.com',
            'birthYear' => 1799,
        ],
        10 => [
            'id' => 10,
            'name' => 'Николай Васильевич Гоголь',
            'email' => 'nikolay_gogol@example.com',
            'birthYear' => 1809,
        ],
        17 => [
            'id' => 17,
            'name' => 'Михаил Юрьевич Лермонтов',
            'email' => 'mikhail_lermontov@example.com',
            'birthYear' => 1814,
        ],
    ],
    'books' => [
        [
            'title' => 'Евгений Онегин',
            'publishedAt' => '1823—1832',
            'author' => 301,
        ],
        [
            'title' => 'Полтава',
            'publishedAt' => '1828—1829',
            'author' => 301,
        ],
        [
            'title' => 'Мёртвые души',
            'publishedAt' => '1842',
            'author' => 10,
        ],
        [
            'title' => 'Сказка о рыбаке и рыбке',
            'publishedAt' => '1833',
            'author' => 301,

        ],
    ],
];
```

Необходимо вывести в формате:

=== Авторы ===

Николай Васильевич Гоголь – nikolay_gogol@example.com - 1809

Александр Сергеевич Пушкин – alexander_pushkin@example.com - 1799

=== Книги ===

Мертвые души – Николай Васильевич Гоголь - 1841

Пиковая дама - Александр Сергеевич Пушкин - 1833

Для вывода я написал следующий код:

```
   echo '=== Авторы ===<br>';
    array_map(function($data){
        echo sprintf('%s – %s – %s',$data['name'], $data['email'], $data['birthYear']) . '<br>';
    }, $data['authors']);
    
    echo '=== Книги ===<br>';
    array_map(function($data){
        echo sprintf('%s – %s – %s',$data['title'], $data['author'], $data['publishedAt']) . '<br>';
    }, $data['books']);
```

Но проблема в том, что таким образом выводится именно ID автора указанный в 'books'. А мне нужен вывод полного имени автора, который указан в 'authors'. Можете, пожалуйста, подсказать или направить как это можно реализовать?

Comment: "я написал" = "скопировал и не понимаю что происходит" ? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1173768/223826

Comment: [где вы вообще все учитесь то](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C)

Comment: @teran, вам есть, что еще добавить? Я самостоятельно изучаю язык, это задание мне никуда не нужно сдавать, вопрос задаю исключительно потому, что встал в тупик и мне нужна помощь. Надеюсь, вы получили удовольствие оставив токсичный комментарий. Спасибо за то, что уделили время.

Comment: используйте для перебора foreach. например, foreach ($data['authors'] as $id => $author), тогда у вас в $author буду данные одного автора

Comment: @Diefair , спасибо большое, всё получилось

Comment: вам ссылки были даны, чтобы вы ознакомились с вопросами ответами ваших собратьев изучающих тот же курс или книгу (есть сомнения, что это хорошая книга). Кто-то видит модное словечко "токсичность", а кто-то бы прошел по линкам и прочитал, о чем там речь, глядишь ознакомился бы с тем. как другие люди решают сходные проблемы.

Answer (score 0):

- `array_map()` используют для преобразования данных. вы же ничего не модифицируете и не возвращаете. С этой целью, если и использовать подобные функции, то `array_walk()`. Хотя вывод кода внутри функций - так себе затея.
- `sprintf` наиболее медленное решение для генерации строки из всех возможных. медленней чем конкатенация и тем более чем подстановка переменных в строку.
- чтобы получить данные автора, необходимо сделать весь массив `data` доступным внутри функции. Для сего можно использовать `use ($data)` но локальный параметр переименовать в какое-нибудь `$v`.
- тогда `$aId = $v['author_id']` и данные автор доступны через `$name = $data[$aId]['name']`. Поскольку ключами массива авторов являются их идентификаторы, то никакие циклы тут не нужны.
- вывод организовать через `"{$v['title']} - {$name}\n"` и т.п.

Answer (score 0):

Встретил это задание в тесте при отборе на стажировку в qsoft. Добавлю, что условиями задачи было запрещено использование функций и сторонних переменных. Сначала тоже пытался выполнить задание через `sprintf`, но не получилось сопоставить id автора из books с именем автора по id в authors. В результате многочасовых мучений, внезапно, нашлось очень простое решение (возможно, костыль, но работает + было принято в качестве ответа)

```
/* ===== Ваш код ниже ===== */

echo '=== Авторы ===<br>';
// Ваш код здесь
foreach ($data['authors'] as $key => $value) {
        echo "$value[name] – $value[email] – $value[birthYear] <br>";
}

echo '=== Книги ===<br>';
foreach ($data['authors'] as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($data['books'] as $kkey => $vvalue) {
        if ($vvalue['author'] == $value['id']) {
            echo "$vvalue[title] – $value[name] – $vvalue[publishedAt] <br>";
        }
    }
}
```